# How to disable search as you type plugin suggestions?

Tags: plugins, api

In Plugins > Add New screen, the plugin table gets automatically filtered as I type the name of a plugin in the search field. Is it possible to disable this functionality and have the table update only after I hit return?

The answer may lie in wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php and/or wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php: wp_ajax_install_plugin().

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty fix** will be to remove/change [`$pluginInstallSearch.on`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/updates.js#L2141) to trigger only on submit. The changed function looks like this. Remember this is not recommended.

```
$pluginInstallSearchOnlyonSubmit = $(".plugin-install-php .search-form.search-plugins");
$pluginInstallSearchOnlyonSubmit.on( 'submit', _.debounce( function( event, eventtype ) {
var $searchTab = $( '.plugin-install-search' ), data, searchLocation;
    data = {
        _ajax_nonce: wp.updates.ajaxNonce,
        s:           $pluginInstallSearchOnlyonSubmit.find('.wp-filter-search').val(),//Set the search input value
        tab:         'search',
        type:        $( '#typeselector' ).val(),
        pagenow:     pagenow
    };
  .........
```

Again, the above function works fine but that's not the way to do it. It just gives an idea as how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = $._data( $('.wp-filter-search')[0], 'events' );
delete( e.keyup );
e.input2 = e.input;
delete( e.input );
$('.wp-filter-search').keypress(function(e) {
    if ( 13 === e.which ) {
        $(this).trigger( 'input2' );
    }
});
```

did it.

I've put together a plugin for this here: https://github.com/srikat/Disable-Dynamic-Plugin-Install-Search